# Windows Server 2012 Local DHCPv6 Stateful & Public Stateless?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6, dhcpv6

I want my LAN to have static IPv6 ULAs from the server's DHCP6, and global IPv6 as well.

So it'd look something like this:

Server

```
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601::1         (public auto)
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fc00:5::1       (local static)
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1%2       (link-local)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1:1%2     (auto)
                                    192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fc05::1         (local)
                                    192.168.1.10
```

Client

```
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601::1         (public auto)
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fc00:5::100     (local from server)
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2601::2         (random public auto)
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1%2       (link-local)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100   (local from server)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1:1%2     (auto)
                                    192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10    (server)
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fc00:5::1         (server)
                                    192.168.1.10    (server)
```

I've tried setting different RA flags and whatnot, but I've had no luck. This is the command I'm running to try and do it:

`netsh int ipv6 set int 19 advertise=enabled routerdiscovery=enabled advertisedefaultroute=disabled managedaddress=enabled otherstateful=enabled store=persistent`

Comment: That range is not valid for assignment. Try a valid range, such as a properly generated ULA range.

Comment: Though you're right, it still doesn't solve it. The server config is like so: `netsh int ipv6 set int 19 advertise=enabled routerdiscovery=enabled advertisedefaultroute=disabled managedaddress=enabled otherstateful=enabled store=persistent` The problem with that is that I can't ping the static IPv6 set on the interface from a client, and the server doesn't pick up a public IPv6.